# Exclaimation point infront of a Python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

What does it mean when you have an exclaimation point `!` infront of a Python function like `head`?

**Example**

```
aapl.to_csv('aapl.csv')
!head aapl.csv
```

Using `head aapl.csv` throws an `invalid syntax` error.

Comment: I guess you are supposed to type this into IPython, where `!` acts as a shell-escape (i.e. the first line would be run in python, dumping the data to disk, the second on the shell, printing out the first ten lines of the newly written file).

Comment: wow I had no idea you could do this in python ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Only IPython

Comment: @filmor That makes sense. My first thought (as a joke) was this is someone coding in Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Ipython, which uses this `!command` syntax for running system commands.
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands